# CSS hover on image issue with hovering on links?

Tags: html, css

So I want to add 2 hover images to my site, yet when I do this, I get a black border cut through the middle of the images and this is due to me having hover on link effects. Here is the code

```
a:hover,a:active
{
color:Black;
outline:ridge;
text-outline:#000;
text-decoration:underline;
font-size:20px;
font-style:italic;
font-style:bold;

}
```

I tried this code from a similar question on stack but it worked to no avail.

```
a:hover img {

a img:hover{border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The code you tried doesn't seem properly formatted. Try this.

```css
a:hover img, a img:hover{
     border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to avoid `!important`. In this case you can just give your images and anchors a class or id and apply the CSS rules you want.

HTML:

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Some link</a>
<img class="image" src="">
```

CSS:

```css
.link:hover, .link:active {
  color:Black;
  outline:ridge;
  text-outline:#000;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-size:20px;
  font-style:italic;
  font-style:bold;
}

.image:hover {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid having such aggressive styles on all a tags site-wide...it will cause lots of headaches like this. Try wrapping your text in p tags for tighter control, or giving either text or images a class like @mrkou suggests.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Xs4tn/

```css
p a:hover, p a:active {
  color:Black;
  outline:ridge;
  text-outline:#000;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-size:20px;
  font-style:italic;
  font-style:bold;
}
```